# How to optimize writting each row of a spark dataframe as a separate file

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

My dataframe has around 1 million records. Below is my code I am using to write each row of a spark dataframe to a separate file. But it takes hours to complete. Any suggestion to tweak this would be really helpful.

```
row_count = df.count()
row_count = 10,000,00
df1 = df.repartition(row_count)
df1.rdd.map(lambda row:row[0]).saveAsTextFile(targetfolder)
```

Comment: This is not a good practice to write each row in separate dataframe This may hamper your performance. Can you please explain the need.

Comment: Hi Pawan, But my target is to write each record into a separate file. I couldn't find any other solution rather than re partitioning to the number of records. My dataframe is having around 10Lakhs of order details, so I need to write each order to each file.

Answer (score 1):

This will hamper the performance and you should consider checking onto logic that if you really need one row in one file.

Still if you want to do it, you can try this not very sure how much performance gain you can get

```
win = window.orderBy('anyColumn')
df2=df.withColumn('row',f.row_number().over(win))
df2.write.partitionBy('row').parquet('path')
```

Not at all recommended though.